# How to set a borderWidth on ChartJS - AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I'm using chart.js in AngularJS. I'm trying to set the `borderWidth` to `1px`.

I've tried

```
this.chart = {
    title: 'Threat Trends',
    labels: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
    series: ['Malware', 'Phishing'],
    data: [this.app.malwareSiteCountWeekly, this.app.phishingSiteCountWeekly],
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: true,
            position: 'bottom'
        }
    },
    borderWidth: 1,
    colors : [this.app.theme.primary, this.app.theme.secondary],
    type: 'bar'
};
```

and

```
<canvas
id="bar"
class="chart chart-bar"
chart-data="$ctrl.chart.data"
chart-type="bar"
chart-colors="$ctrl.chart.colors"
chart-labels="$ctrl.chart.labels"
chart-series="$ctrl.chart.series"
chart-options="$ctrl.chart.options"
chart-dataset-override="preOverride">
</canvas>
```

I kept getting

[image]

Any hints for me ?

Answer (score 4):

You can configure the borderwidht per dataset as axtck pointed out in his example. You can also set the default to 1 like this, this will change it for all of your charts: `Chart.defaults.global.elements.rectangle.borderWidth = 1;`.

You will have to put this line before you create your chart.

EDIT:
If you want to make it different for only 1 of your charts you can configure the rectangle element in the options and set the `borderWidth` like this:

```
options: {
    elements: {
        rectangle: {
            borderWidth: 15
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for mentioning me! I didn't know you could set it globally like that.

Comment: I tried that it works, but it affects my other charts. I have to make sure it only affects this one specific chart.

Comment: Updated answer for you how to fix it

Answer (score 3):

You should set the border width for the dataset you would like to apply it to.

Try this:

```js
data: {
    datasets: [{
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [this.app.malwareSiteCountWeekly, this.app.phishingSiteCountWeekly]
    }]
};
```